# touch button aerea (iPhone,iPad)

Tags: iphone, ipad, touch

I have got this situation:
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
   
this is the photo: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/826/iconepe.png/
the two images are little 20 pixel x pixel, If I click on them, nothing happens, if I click oh the left on them, the link works. I should make images bigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are missing the buttons with your finger.

> The comfortable minimum size of tappable UI elements is 44 x 44
>   points.

According to the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Characteristics/Characteristics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH7-SW1)

If you need to keep the images this small, one workaround would be to increase the size (frame) of the button and keep the image (the image must be set as a button image, not background image). This way you'd have a bigger zone that will accept input and still use the same image.

Comment: I have got bigger images (44x44), but the same problems

Answer (score 0):

Ask your designer to make the image bigger, by using a transparent space around it.. 20x20 is too small to touch..  Apple says that the avg finger tap is 44x44 (from WWDC). All table rows are recommended to be at least that height. Use a transparent padding to make your image atleast 44 * 44.